# No ethernet/wireless connection after dist upgrade - "network UNCLAIMED"

Tags: networking, drivers, wifi, ethernet, xubuntu

I did an upgrade from Xubuntu 12.04 to 12.10, and I can't connect to the internet now.

When I press the network button on the panel, I see "No network devices available" on top (greyed out), then "VPN Connections", "Enable Networking" with a checkmark next to it, "Information" (greyed out) and "Edit".

Here's the output from some commands that seem relevant: 
 `~ % lspci | grep -i ethernet
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
~ % lspci | grep -i network
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 (rev 34)
~ % sudo lshw -C network
PCI (sysfs)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 34
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7c00000-f7c01fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
~ % uname -a
Linux bleen 3.5.0-030500-generic #201207211835 SMP Sat Jul 21 22:35:55 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
~ % ifconfig 
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback

          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:472 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:35080 (35.0 KB)  TX bytes:35080 (35.0 KB)
~ % ifconfig eth0 up
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`

I think that UNCLAIMED means I don't have a driver for the Ethernet controller. It seems that the driver should be called something including 816 (I don't remember where I found that), and it does seem to be missing:

`~ % lsmod | grep 816
~ %`

I tried [downloading](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) and installing the driver (after moving on a USB stick from a computer with a connection), but I get this issue:

`~/r8168-8.037.00 % sudo ./autorun.sh 
Check old driver and unload it.
Build the module and install
make: * /lib/modules/3.5.0-030500-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make1:  [clean] Error 2
make: ** [clean] Error 2`

Not sure what to do next.

Comment: For your last issue (when compiling the module from source), you probably need to install the kernel headers: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and try again.

Comment: @JosephR. That tells me `linux-headers-3.5.0-030500-generic is already the newest version.` and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please check that both these directories are available on your system: `/lib/modules/3.5.0-030500-generic` and `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-030500-generic`.

Comment: @JosephR. They are. The first one just doesn't have a `build` subdirectory in it.

Comment: On my system (Debian Wheezy), `build` is actually a symlink to `/usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)`. So simply add the symlink: `sudo ln -sv /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`

Comment: Which driver did you download? Where from? Is this the [official realtek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) one?

Comment: @JosephR. That made the driver install go through! Now to figure out what to do next...

Comment: @terdon Yes, that one, "LINUX driver for kernel 3.x and 2.6.x and 2.4.x" specifically.

Comment: @weronika If the install went through correctly, usually a reboot is all that's required.

Comment: @JosephR. Yep, I have an ethernet connection now, thanks! Still no wireless - I guess I just need to repeat the process for the Centrino Wireless-N 1030 (still showing up as UNCLAIMED in lshw).

Comment: @weronika Glad to see things starting to work out. Two more points: 1- Was/were the NIC(s) working out of the box before the upgrade? 2- If you're able to get the wireless working in a similar way, please answer your own question summarizing the steps you've taken.

Comment: @JosephR. I got the laptop with Xubuntu pre-installed on it - things were working out of the box as far as I could tell, but I don't know if the vendor needed to do any tweaking before I got it. I'll add the answer when I have the rest working. Thanks again!

Comment: @weronika You're most welcome :). From what you say, it seems that a kernel upgrade is what caused the breakage. If the upgrade upgraded your kernel, your bootloader (GRUB/Lilo?) will probably provide alternative entries for booting with the older kernel. If that's the case, can you try booting into one of these and seeing if things work?

Comment: @JosephR. You're right, if I boot with 3.5.0-41-generic, everything works! (The default is 3.5.0-030500-generic - I don't actually know which one is newer or what the difference is, hmm.)

Comment: @weronika I don't know either. The moral of the story: keep the driver source(s) and compilation instructions (e.g. symlink `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` before compiling) somewhere you can easily return to for future upgrades.

Comment: @JosephR. Yup! I posted an answer here, and saved the info for myself so I can refer to it next time. I'm so glad you thought of the kernel thing! I wouldn't have, and it fixed all the various problems I was having.

Comment: I had this issue after updating the kernel within Ubuntu 16.04. Unbelievable: The `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` plus a reboot was all it needed to get the network back. Wonderful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question turned out to have two answers, both suggested by @JosephR in the comments.

**1)** Fixing the `/lib/modules/3.5.0-030500-generic/build: No such file or directory` error while trying to install the ethernet driver just needed a `sudo ln -sv /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r) /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` - after I did that, the driver install from source worked fine, and I got an ethernet connection.

(Presumably repeating the process with the driver for the wireless controller would have made that work too, but I didn't actually try, due to solution #2.)

**2)** It turned out that if I just booted with the other kernel that was already installed (3.5.0-41-generic instead of 3.5.0-030500-generic - I don't actually know what the difference is), both the ethernet and the wireless worked fine!

It also solved some other problems I was having after the upgrade.  So I changed the default boot kernel to that, and will probably stick with that unless I run into other issues.

Comment: I think I might have a similar problem. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163276/what-does-it-mean-when-lshw-says-a-wireless-adapter-to-be-unclaimed-while-iw and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163028/why-does-my-wlan0-stop-working. I need to figure out which `linux-headers` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem when a working wifi connection stopped working after a dist-upgrade. (I have HP Pavilion g6, the driver being ralink3290).
The problem was that the upgrade modified the module and so the driver that was being used was not the same as was supposed to be used by my system.

- Use this command to see which wireless controller hardware you are using

  ```
  $ lspci | grep Network
  ```

  The output for me was: `Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290`

All I had to do was:

- Check if the conflicting wireless drivers are still blacklisted

  ```
  $ sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
  ```
- Add these lines, if not already present:

  ```
  # Conflicting wireless drivers with rt3290sta
  blacklist rt2800pci
  ```
- Load the correct module on boot

  ```
  $ sudo gedit /etc/modules`
  ```

(Check for your own module as per your drivers)

- Add this line at the end of the file: `rt3290sta`
- Update the modification you just made:

  ```
  $ sudo update-initramfs -u`
  ```
- Restart your system

  ```
  $ sudo shutdown -r now
  ```

You should now be able to view the wireless connections in the Network Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I need to give an updated answer to this question, because this also happened to me, this year. In my case, after the last update to the Kernel all older (discontinued) firmware was dropped and so I was left without it.

First, YES, UNCLAIMED means: no driver (or firmware interface) found that are registered with the OS to handle the device.

See the output of:

```
dmesg
```

[image]

You can now go the GIT Route, clone the repository, find the appropriate firmware and install it:

```
sudo cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Or see if the manufacturer is listed and indexed here: 
 [wireless wiki drivers](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers)

[image]

After restarting:

[image]

As we can see Linux tried to use newer drivers but found only the `iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode`

Regards.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion if my min, max and nothing in between supported versions are not found in git repo?