# What does it mean, when lshw says a wireless adapter `UNCLAIMED`, while iwconfig doesn't find it?

Tags: wifi, networkcard, pci

What does it mean, when `iwconfig` doesn't find (i.e. report) an internal wireless adapter, while `lshw` says it `UNCLAIMED`?  This happens after I notice it not working, and unload and reload its module `iwlwifi`. (This is a thinkpad T400 laptop running Ubuntu 12.04)

If the adapter is in loose connection to the PCI or whatever it should be connected to, can `lshw` still find (i.e. report) it?

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f4200000-f4201fff
```

Comment: I think I might have a similar problem to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93471/no-ethernet-wireless-connection-after-dist-upgrade-network-unclaimed? I have to figure out which `linux-headers` will work?