# Installed Docker, then lost internet connection on reboot! [Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS]

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers, docker, internet

Has anybody used docker on Ubuntu and later found they cannot connect to the internet? I started using it for the first time yesterday and today I can't connect via wifi or ethernet!

I have spent the last day or so troubleshooting and have found that the drivers are now missing (at least that's what I think is causing the problem).

Apparently the kernel is supposed to take care of this in my current Linux version, so it's not just a matter of downloading new ones.

• ifconfig reveals no wifi or ethernet adapters.

• lspci shows that they are there.

• lshw tells me that they don't have their drivers.

I have tried downloading and installing several packages by transferring them by usb, but nothing seems to work for me.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

[image]
[image]

I really not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: I would check the kernel log...

Comment: I had a check of the kernel log and it had 48 hours worth of logs (which covers the time from when I installed docker).  


Unfortunately, I don't really know what I'm checking for.  I tried doing searches using key words like 'network', 'wireless' and 'AR9285', etc. but didn't see anything stand out as being useful.


I uploaded it to uploadedit.com if someone who knows what to look for wants to take a look.  Here's the link: [kernel log](http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1500424958877.txt)


Or if someone can tell me what I need to look for that would be great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After considerable digging around and being on the brink of resorting to a fresh install of the operating system.  I discovered a [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93471/no-ethernet-wireless-connection-after-dist-upgrade-network-unclaimed) by @weronika who suggested that booting from another kernel might help.

Not being sure how to do this I did more digging and found a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216398/set-older-kernel-as-default-grub-entry) on askubuntu.com by a user called @DaimyoKirby who explained how to change the grub file.

I made a copy of /etc/default/grub calling it /etc/default/grub.bak with the command

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

and made the change suggested by @DaimyoKirby to /etc/default/grub by changing

> GRUB_DEFAULT=0

to

> GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-81-generic"

(I found my previous version of the kernel by looking in the /usr/src directory).  After this I rebuilt grub with

`sudo update-grub`

On reboot I was back to my previous version of the kernel and once again had an internet connection.  I'm not sure if it was necessary but considering there were pending updates I did a

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and a

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

as was suggested.

After this, I thought I'd try going back to the newer kernel I was on originally, hoping everything would still work, and it did.  I made a copy of the grub file again just to be safe calling it grub.prev.bak, swapped the other backup file with current grub file, and once again rebuilt grub.

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.prev.bak
sudo cp /etc/default/grub.bak /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

On reboot I was back with the latest kernel version I was using and still had internet.  `ifconfig` revealed the once missing network interfaces.

I once again did a

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and after this I was golden. =D