# Connection problems after Docker install

Tags: networking, docker

I have installed Docker normally and everything worked fine but after a reboot, I lost my network (PCIe Wireless Adapter, Wired Connection, and even USB Tethering). I found **a lot** of similar content, but none works for me. I even removed [Docker completely](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021506/1092324) but still with the problem. I don't know now if Docker was the problem, but it seems a big coincidence.

Also, on Live USB, I don't have problems. Even on an older Kernel version, **it works**.

Before removed Docker, I tried to set `bip` on `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```json
{
  "bip": "172.31.0.1/16"
}
```

Doesn't work as well.

I tried to boot into the older Kernel which has the connection working and reinstall the newer:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic
```

Both controllers show as UNCLAIMED on -43 Kernel:

```bsh
$ sudo lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
```

On Wi-Fi Settings, I have "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found".

**ifconfig:**

```bsh
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4450  bytes 319294 (319.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4450  bytes 319294 (319.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It does not seem like a driver problem, because as I said, it was working fine before the reboot.

I also tried:

```bsh
sudo rfkill list
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Can someone help me, please?

### System info:

**OS Name:** Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

**Kernel:** 5.8.0-44-generic (on 5.8.0-43-generic it works)

**OS Type:** 64-bit

**GNOME Version:** 3.36.8

### Similar issues

https://forums.docker.com/t/cant-access-internet-after-installing-docker-in-a-fresh-ubuntu-18-04-machine/53416

[Installed Docker, then lost internet connection on reboot! [Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379351/installed-docker-then-lost-internet-connection-on-reboot-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts)

Comment: The reboot might have switched to a newer kernel that is giving problems. Try at the GRUB prompt to use an older kernel version. I don't see the relation with Docker here.

Comment: I think I didn't explain right. The reboot made me lose my connection, after some hours of searching for a solution, I tried to switch to an older Kernel, and saw that it was not affected. About Docker, I saw some people saying that the Docker could have taken a new network interface, which conflicts with my real one. I think that I could have done some other mess before the reboot, but I can't identify or even revert it.

Comment: The startup messages should mention the two NICs in one shape or another. Also check if the required kernel module exists at all - was it removed? Are you, per chance, using a different /lib/modules subdirectory that doesn't contain that module?

Comment: I'm sorry @berndbausch, I didn't understand. I have never changed anything on the old kernel which network works, so I think that it has all modules.

Comment: What did you not understand?

Comment: I don't know what NICs means or even which kernel module you're talking about

Comment: Same problem. But I have no older kernel. This is the first install of Debian on this machine.